# Format time with French style java

Tags: java, date, time, format

Is there a way to format the time to look like this:

**10h23**

I used the SimpleDateFormat and saw all the patterns available, but I want to know if there's a way to have the time like that or if I will have to build it myself.

I also tried

`DateFormat tf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.FRANCE);`

but it prints like **11 h 01 CST**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh'h'mm");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Printed:

```
12h11
```